# PostgreSQL duplicate a user with same permission

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm currently working on some project migrations and I want to **create a single user in our New PostgreSQL** with the same set of roles and permissions as the one in **existing PostgreSQL**.

I have searched regarding this but haven't found any answers.

[how to create duplicate role of a user in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591557/how-to-create-duplicate-role-of-a-user-in-postgres) -> This solution is for same PostgreSQL instance

https://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/81-Backing-up-Login-Roles-aka-Users-and-Group-Roles.html -> Copies all the users with the same username and password. I don't want that.

**Note**: I don't want to copy the user ( username and password can be different, however, can be the same if the solution is easier), all I want is to create a new user in a new instance based on roles and permission in the existing PostgreSQL.

Comment: The typical approach is to bundle privileges in roles, so you just grant the role to a new user. As a user and a role is essentially the same thing, you can simply grant the existing user to the new user, thus the new user has the same privileges.

Answer (score 1):

That is not easy to do, because permissions are not stored on the user, but on the object: every table, view, function etc. knows which user has which permissions on it. So to copy the permissions of a user, you'd have to copy all the object definitions.

So that is what you can do: run `pg_dump -s dbname` to dump all metadata of a database and restore them to the new database. If you want to change the user name in the new database, just rename the role.